# clarification using css in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Code below works which came from a tutorial ive been following. i just want to understand some parts of the code.

```
function Arrow_Points() {
    var s = $('#container').find('.item');
    $.each(s, function (i, obj) {
        var posLeft = $(obj).css("left");

        if (posLeft == "0px") {
            html = "<span class='rightCorner'></span>";
            $(obj).prepend(html);
        } else {
            html = "<span class='leftCorner'></span>";
            $(obj).prepend(html);
        }
    });
}
```

1) what does the `i` in function used for? `$.each(s,function(i,obj){` it was never used  after *it* was declared.

2) this is my css for `.item`

```
.item {
width: 408px;
float: left;
min-height:50px;
}
```

the condition is `if(posLeft == "0px")` how did he/she came up with the value `0px`?
are `left` floats default position is `0px`?

Comment: posLeft was defined earlier as the objects `left` position, which is used in CSS absolute, relative, and fixed positioning. The default position for a `left` is indeed 0.

Comment: The [.each() API for jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### CSS:

`float` makes the element stick to left side of its parent container element.

So if the element is nested in the body element it should be predictably be on the left corner **BUT** css `left` must be explicitly defined in order to return a value .

How ever I see no relation between `.item` and this if condition.

#### Each:

As for for the `i` it used for the index, when it's not used it is sometimes marked as `_`. You need to declare it if you want to handle each object as `obj` since it is the second argument this [function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) takes and javscript "can't" guess what you meant when you wrote `obj` without it's counterpart. `obj` however is optional so if you only pass `index` it will work.

Answer (score 0):

the `i` in the `$.each` iteration refers to the index of the element you are iterating over.

Specifically, for any Enumerable `s`, at every iteration of `$.each()`, `s[i]===obj`

See [the official documentation of $.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)